# Partial loading of PDF, stop loading before overlay

Tags: pdf, edit, markup, redaction

I have a pdf that briefly flashes information that is under an overlay. Unflatten doesn't work. Is there a way to edit the pdf's data to manually remove the overlay layer, or some way to stop it from loading before the overlay layer is applied? The basis of the problem is removing an improperly applied redaction.

The only thing I can think of right now would be to record the screen in high enough FPS to be able to pause and read the information.

Anybody have a more sophisticated solution? Thank you for your help!

Comment: If you were fluent in PDF internals, you'd take a PDF structure browser (RUPS, PDF Debugger, ...) and analyze the content of your PDF. As soon as you determined a way to recognize those overlays, you'd write a program with your favorite PDF library that removed those overlays.

Comment: Thank you for the road map @mkl, this is exactly the type of response I was hoping for! I see you are specifically interested in PDF related topics, people like me are glad people like you exist to teach us! Cheers